# How to check Pusher Channel is available?

Tags: pusher

I am using Pusher for channels and live streaming.

I create channel. Can I check status of a particular channel that if it is created or is streaming or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's no action to create a channel; you can publish data to a channel and subscribe to one. When a a channel is subscribed to it is occupied and when there are no subscribers it is vacant.

You can check whether a channel has any subscribers (is occupied) by querying the HTTP API for channel information:
https://pusher.com/docs/server_api_guide/interact_rest_api#channel-information

Some libraries have helper functions for this e.g. the PHP library:
https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php#get-information-about-a-channel